# Buildozer выдает ошибку при компиляции

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

пытаюсь скомпилировать проект с buildozer + kivymd, но получаю ошибку

> configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Но я так и не понял почему сишный компилятор не может создать исполняемые файлы. Как я могу исправить это?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS x86_64
Buildozer: 1.2.0
Python: 3.8

стоит на виртуалке, устанавливал buildozer и зависимости к нему по официальным докам.
лог:

```
  RAN: /home/nikita/bomb/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --enable-shared --enable-ipv6 ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=yes ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no --without-ensurepip ac_cv_little_endian_double=yes --prefix=/usr/local --exec-prefix=/usr/local --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --with-openssl=/home/nikita/bomb/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/openssl/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/openssl1.1

  STDOUT:
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking for python3.8... python3.8
checking for python interpreter for cross build... python3.8
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "linux"
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... /home/nikita/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/nikita/bomb/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/android-build':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,kivymd,fake_useragent,requests,colorama --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/nikita/bomb/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'xfce-'
#     LANG = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     DISPLAY = ':0.0'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '2ddb1d6ca48e4092966ab70d9ff999e8'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_VTNR = '1'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/tmp/ssh-nqSTaX2iV1RA/agent.527'
#     GLADE_CATALOG_PATH = ':'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '1'
#     HUSHLOGIN = 'FALSE'
#     USER = 'nikita'
#     GLADE_MODULE_PATH = ':'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'xfce'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/efbf8e46_64d2_417a_94d4_7af8e536cb78'
#     PWD = '/home/nikita/bomb'
#     HOME = '/home/nikita'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:15756'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '559'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share'
#     GLADE_PIXMAP_PATH = ':'
#     MAIL = '/var/mail/nikita'
#     WINDOWPATH = '1'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5202'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'XFCE'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.29'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     SHLVL = '2'
#     LOGNAME = 'nikita'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/nikita/.Xauthority'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg'
#     PATH = '/home/nikita/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/nikita/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/ubuntu:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/569,unix/ubuntu:/tmp/.ICE-unix/569'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     _ = '/home/nikita/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/nikita/bomb/__pycache__'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/nikita/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/nikita/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/nikita/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему выполнив `$ buildozer android clean`